# persist data in mnesia table locally

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I am using mnesia to store data from within a chicago_boss app. I create the table and store the data as follows:

```
mnesia:create_table(connection, [{record_name, connection},
    {storage_properties, [{ets, [compressed]}, {dets, [{auto_save, 5000}]} ]}]).

mnesia:dirty_write(#connection{pid=WebSocketId, name=EventType}).
```

My mnesia info is as below:

```
(sample_app@blanes-mbp-2)6> mnesia:info().
---> Processes holding locks <--- 
---> Processes waiting for locks <--- 
---> Participant transactions <--- 
---> Coordinator transactions <---
---> Uncertain transactions <--- 
---> Active tables <--- 
connection     : with 0        records occupying 305      words of mem
schema         : with 2        records occupying 554      words of mem
===> System info in version "4.11", debug level = none <===
opt_disc. Directory "/Users/blane/erlang/sample_app/Mnesia.sample_app@blanes-mbp-2" is NOT used.
use fallback at restart = false
running db nodes   = ['sample_app@blanes-mbp-2']
stopped db nodes   = [] 
master node tables = []
remote             = []
ram_copies         = [connection,schema]
disc_copies        = []
disc_only_copies   = []
[{'sample_app@blanes-mbp-2',ram_copies}] = [schema,connection]
4 transactions committed, 0 aborted, 0 restarted, 0 logged to disc
0 held locks, 0 in queue; 0 local transactions, 0 remote
0 transactions waits for other nodes: []
ok
```

My issue is every time I stop my boss server the data in my table disappears. How would I persist this data locally so its still there when I start/stop my server?

Answer (score 3):

> {disc_copies, Nodelist}, where Nodelist is a list of the nodes where
>   this table is supposed to have disc copies. If a table replica is of
>   type disc_copies, all write operations on this particular replica of
>   the table are written to disc as well as to the RAM copy of the table.
>
> It is possible to have a replicated table of type disc_copies on one
>   node, and another type on another node. The default value is [].

You can add this `{disc_copies, [node()]}` when create the table.